# Need to interchange the textview when middle button click

Tags: android, animation, uitextview

First consider my layout 1). chennai 2). Route 3).Bangalore

When my middle button(Route) clicks need to interchange the text like 1).Bangalore 3).Chennai
When the text is interchanging need to animate the button as well as text 
Note. i have looked this concept in sample app but no idea to do

Please suggest or provide related link

Thanks

Comment: what you have try post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this sample code:-

Explanation :-There are two buttons in layout 1).Edit 2).Done  one above other( Edit:- Visible and Done:- visibility Gone)

After calling the below function the button will animate (rotate around  x-axis) and its text will change to Done. Whats happening behind the scene is that the visibility of Edit becomes gone and visibility of Done becomes visible .

```
public void flipit() {

        Edit = (Button) form.findViewById(R.id.next2);
        Done = (Button) form.findViewById(R.id.next);
        Interpolator accelerator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
        Interpolator decelerator = new DecelerateInterpolator();

        final Button visibleButton;
        final Button invisibleButton;

        if (Edit.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            visibleButton = Done;
            invisibleButton = Edit;
        } else {
            visibleButton = Edit;
            invisibleButton = Done;
        }

        ObjectAnimator vToI = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(visibleButton, "rotationY", 0f, 90f);
        vToI.setDuration(500);
        vToI.setInterpolator(accelerator);
        final ObjectAnimator Itov = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(invisibleButton, "rotationY", -90f, 0f);
        Itov.setDuration(500);
        Itov.setInterpolator(decelerator);

        vToI.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator anim) {
                visibleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Itov.start();
                invisibleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        vToI.start();

    }
```